# Simple recursive tree in PHP / MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, recursion, tree, family-tree

I have this table in MySQL:

```
id       name            mother
1        grandma         0
2        myuncle         1
3        mymom           1
4        me              3
5        mysister        3
6        myson           4
7        new_grandma_son 1
```

I almacenate this info in an array called `data[]`

```
$data=array(
        array("id"=>1,"name"=>"grandma",        "mother"=>0),
        array("id"=>2,"name"=>"myuncle",        "mother"=>1),
        array("id"=>3,"name"=>"mymom",          "mother"=>1),
        array("id"=>4,"name"=>"me",             "mother"=>3),
        array("id"=>5,"name"=>"mysister",       "mother"=>3),
        array("id"=>6,"name"=>"myson",          "mother"=>4),
        array("id"=>7,"name"=>"new_grandma_son","mother"=>1)
    );
```

And for make a family tree I am using this recursive function:

```
function tree($data, $mom = 0, $level = 0){
     foreach ($data as $row){
          if ($row['mother'] == $mom) {
               echo str_repeat("-", $level).$row['name']."<br>";
               tree($data, $row['id'], $level);
          }
          else $level++;
     }
}
```

When I call the function `tree($data);` it shows this:

```
grandma
-myuncle (level 1)
-mymom
----me (level 4??)
---------myson (level 9??)
----mysister
----new_grandma_son (level 4??)
```

I have the mistake in the `else $level++;`, because is adding levels when `$row['mother'] != $mom`, going through all the rows, but I don't know how to make it.
Anyone knows? Thank you.

**Solution (By Frits van Campen):**

```
               tree($data, $row['id'], $level+1);

          // (eliminate this else $level++; )
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

```
function tree($data,$mom=0,$level=0){
     foreach($data as $row){
          if($row['mother']==$mom){
               echo str_repeat("-",$level).$row['name']."<br>";
               tree($data,$row['id'],$level+1);
          }
     }
}
```

I *think* this fixes your code. Can you supply the `$data` so I can test it?

Comment: I edited my question ;) and I works!! but so strange... because at the begining I tried to put $level++; just before that function: 
echo str_repeat("-",$level).$row['name']."<br>";
$level++;
tree($data,$row['id'],$level);

And it didn't work. I didn't try your solution because i thought it was the same...! Thank you very much ;)

Comment: You don't want `$level++`, you only need `$level+1` whenever you go one level deeper.

Comment: You can use also ++$lavel. tree($data,$row['id'],++$level); But not tree($data,$row['id'],$level++);

Comment: I did with my logic for file n folder structure but your `$level+1` solution saved my day.

Answer (score 1):

You may try like this, which returns value in a Array format.
I used this function for Item category Tree,

```
    function categoryDropDown($categoryArray, $parentId, $level, $options)
{   
    $level++;
    foreach ($categoryArray  as  $array)
    {
        if($array['parentId'] == $parentId)
        {
            $opt = str_repeat(">> ", $level-1) . $array['name'] ;         
            $options[$array['id']] =  $opt;
            $newParent = $array['id'];              
            $options = categoryDropDown($categoryArray, $newParent, $level , $options);         
        }
    }   
    return $options;    
}
```

----output----

```
//Array Key contains category Id.


Array
(
    [1] => Electronics
    [2] => >> Mobile
    [5] => >> >> Mobile Accessories
    [7] => >> >> >> Sub Category 1
    [9] => >> >> >> Sub Category 3
    [3] => >> Laptop
    [6] => >> >> Laptop Accessories
    [8] => >> >> >> Sub Category 2
    [10] => >> >> >> Sub Category 4
    [4] => >> Tablet
    [11] => Main Category 2
)
```

You can refer some advance version of this code at here [How to display select multiple drop down from using array in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38824711/how-to-display-select-multiple-drop-down-from-using-array-in-php/38828092#38828092)

Answer (score 0):

Cant you just replace the `str_repeat("-", $level)` with `str_repeat("-", $row['mother'])`?

Or maybe in your case `str_repeat("-", $row['mother'] - 1)` as you don't want to start with a `-` in front of grandma.